# Dumping Mocha Tests in Wicket Pages

Tags: java, javascript, testing, wicket, mocha.js

I have a large code base written in Java/Wicket. I also have a bunch of javascript files that uses backbone.js and require.js.

I'm planning on implementing a testing suite with mocha.js. I have mocha tests written in a js file. How do I dump these tests into a genericTestPage.html so that I can get the tests running in browser and served by my application? I don't have a deep grasp of wicket, so am unsure how html pages are served and loaded by it.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: why do you want your HTML page generated by test framework (Mocha) should be served in production mode by your application ?
If you really want to do this then you just need to copy this page in src/main/webapp folder. Then you can reach it by loading http://host:port/[contextPath/]ThePageGeneratedByMocha.html

A good place to do the copying is Maven's post-test/pre-package phase, if you use Maven.

In any case your question has nothing to do with Wicket.